# What does a CMSampleBuffer's sample presentation time represent?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Our app is using AVFoundation to capture video, display, manipulate, and export the video using its sample buffers.  I am trying to understand what the `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(_:)` CMTime actually represents.

For example, when video capture begins, the first sample's presentation time is 93 hours and 5 minutes.  I don't understand where this value comes from.  Using the first sample's presentation time to start the AVAssetWriter session creates 93 hours of black frames before video playback begins.

Comment: Can you post the example `CMTime` value you're seeing returned as 93 hours?

Comment: @JAL Here's the representation in seconds: `347851.930463783`... and the CMTime representation: `{value = 347957883945123, timescale = 1000000000}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's based on a mach time, which means number of ticks from last reboot. You can create such CMTime with this code:

```
  mach_timebase_info_data_t timeInfo;
  mach_timebase_info(&timeInfo);
  CMTime time = CMTimeMake(mach_absolute_time() * timeInfo.numer / timeInfo.denom, 1000000000);
```

Or use this to get it already converted to number of seconds.
`double seconds = CACurrentMediaTime();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it worked for my needs :) . But can can you explain a bit further the formula you used there ? and why is the timescale 1000000000.